# Error: no repository definition for @local. Please add them via 'helm repo add'

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am getting  "no repository definition for @local." while running "helm dependency update"  in influxdb. What could be the reason? I have added influxdb repo also.
I have shared all logs below

```
/home/ravi/influxdb>helm dependency update
Error: no repository definition for @local. Please add them via 'helm repo add'
/home/ravi/influxdb>

/home/ravi/influxdb>helm repo list
NAME        URL                         
influxdata  https://helm.influxdata.com/
/home/ravi/influxdb>
/home/ravi/influxdb>ls
Chart.yaml  files  LICENSE  OWNERS  README.md  requirements.yaml  templates  values.yaml
/home/ravi/influxdb>

/home/ravi/influxdb>helm dependency update
Error: no repository definition for @local. Please add them via 'helm repo add'
/home/ravi/influxdb>

    
/home/ravi/influxdb>tree
.
├── Chart.yaml
├── files
│   └── backup-retention-script.sh
├── LICENSE
├── OWNERS
├── README.md
├── requirements.yaml
├── templates
│   ├── backup-cronjob.yaml
│   ├── backup-pvc.yaml
│   ├── backup-retention-configmap.yaml
│   ├── backup-retention-cronjob.yaml
│   ├── configmap.yaml
│   ├── ingress.yaml
│   ├── init-config.yaml
│   ├── meta-configmap.yaml
│   ├── meta-service.yaml
│   ├── meta-statefulset.yaml
│   ├── NOTES.txt
│   ├── post-install-set-auth.yaml
│   ├── secret.yaml
│   ├── serviceaccount.yaml
│   ├── service.yaml
│   └── statefulset.yaml
└── values.yaml

2 directories, 23 files
/home/ravi/influxdb>
```

Content of chart file is given below:

```
/home/influxdb>cat Chart.yaml 
apiVersion: v1
name: influxdb
version: 4.9.14
appVersion: 1.8.4
description: Scalable datastore for metrics, events, and real-time analytics.
keywords:
  - influxdb
  - database
  - timeseries
  - influxdata
home: https://www.influxdata.com/time-series-platform/influxdb/
sources:
  - https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb
maintainers:
  - name: rawkode
    email: rawkode@influxdata.com
  - name: gitirabassi
    email: giacomo@influxdata.com
  - name: aisuko
    email: urakiny@gmail.com
  - name: naseemkullah
    email: naseem@transit.app
engine: gotpl
/home/influxdb>
```

As you can see above, I have already added the repo list. Can anyone let me know why I am getting this error?

```
/home/influxdb>cat requirements.yaml 
dependencies:
  - name: ric-common
    version: ^3.1.0
    repository: "@local"          ----> what is this? and how to add?

/home/influxdb>
```

I have further gone into ric-common dir and tried to add repo as below, but no luck

```
/home/dbaas/charts/ric-common>helm repo add ric-common '@local'
Error: could not find protocol handler for:
```

Answer (score -1):

You only can use `@local` if the repository has been added to the repository index file.
Based on your directory tree, I haven't seen folder of dependency.
Link references:
https://helm.sh/docs/chart_best_practices/dependencies/#repository-urls

Comment: I have added the content of chart.yaml in main thread as you asked for. thanks. but as i said, i have already repo added see in "helm repo ls" output
i have added conent of requirements.yaml. what is @local here and how to fix this